# Why is my Reducer not receiving my Actions? (Using React & Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

These are my current action creators, they run fine & return actions as usual. I've tested with some logging, its working here:

```
export function stateToEntry() {
    return { type: types.STATE_TO_ENTRY, formState: 'entry-mode'};
}

export function stateToEdit() {
    return { type: types.STATE_TO_EDIT, formState: 'edit-mode'};
}

export function stateToDelete() {
    return { type: types.STATE_TO_DELETE, formState: 'delete-mode'};
}
```

This is my current reducer which doesn't receive my actions. I've tested here, it seems that I can't even log into the console:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function formStateReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.STATE_TO_ENTRY:
            console.log('entry-mode');
            return {formState: action.formState};
        case types.STATE_TO_EDIT:
            //console.log('edit-mode');
            return {formState: action.formState};
        case types.STATE_TO_DELETE:
            //console.log('delete-mode');
            return {formState: action.formState};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is my combined reducer. The locations reducer works fine but I'm getting a null on my formState so it's linked correctly inside the store. :

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    locations,
    formStates
});


export default rootReducer;
```

What could I have probably missed?

Comment: Code looks fine except you're defaulting the state to an empty array when from code below it seems you want your state to be an object with a property `formState`. That may not be what you want. Besides that problem, it looks like you're not giving nearly enough information to determine what you're doing wrong.

Comment: check that you are adding and including the reducers correctly

Comment: I just found out that I'm not properly dispatching my actions. I'm using `formStateActions.stateToEntry();` which I think isn't correct.

Comment: It should be `dispatch(formStateActions.stateToEntry())`

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr I'm using `bindActionCreators(locationActions, formStateActions, dispatch)`. How do I combine them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: `bindActionCreators` ... Turns an object whose values are action creators, into an object with the same keys, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly.

So, you're using it wrong, try this:

```
let foo = {
    location: bindActionCreators(locationActions, dispatch),
    form: bindActionCreators(formActions, dispatch)
}
// later in your code -- will dispatch that action automatically
foo.location.someActionFromLocationActionsObject()
```